# How to remove a specific pattern from a string in R?

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have this string (for example).

```
str <- "T gwed is atyrt mtt yfdgfg grter effgf y"
```

I want to remove lone occurring alphabets from this string ('T' at the start and 'y' at the end in this case) and output should be

```
"gwed is atyrt mtt yfdgfg grter effgf"
```

I used this

```
str <- gsub("[A-Za-z] ", "", str)
```

But it gives this as a result.

```
[1] "gweiatyrmtyfdgfgrtey"
```

Here it considers cases like "gwed " also and hence it merges every word of the string.

How do i achieve my aim?

Also, I have this huge text with thousands of strings (not just a single string), so keep this in mind while providing an answer.

Comment: `str()` is a function (and a very useful one), it is a good rule to not name objects the same as existing functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str <- "T gwed is atyrt mtt yfdgfg grter effgf y"

gsub(" ?\\<[[:alpha:]]\\> ?", "", str)

## [1] "gwed is atyrt mtt yfdgfg grter effgf"
```

You need to use the special character to denote word boundaries, i.e., `\\<` and `\\>`. The  `_?` (where `_` is a space) denotes that you also want to remove single spaces around the single letters (if present). See `?regex` for more.

Answer (score 1):

Another option wthout using regular expressions:

```
xx <- unlist(strsplit(str, " "))
paste(xx[nchar(xx)>1],collapse=' ')

[1] "gwed is atyrt mtt yfdgfg grter effgf"
```